# Django custom decorator not wrapping

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I'm trying to create a custom decorator in Django and apply it to a class based view in the URLs file.  This is the decorator in decorators.py.  It uses functools.  I'm not able to get the wrapper function to execute the second log command.

```
def user_isnt_blocked(func):
    logger.info("user_not_blocked call " + func.__name__)
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("user_not_blocked wrapper")
        return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Right now, the decorator does nothing as I'm first trying to figure out how to get it to do the wrapping part - i.e. it is **not** logging the "user_not_blocked wrapper".  The initial call is logged - it **does** print out "user_not_blocked call".  The pertinent url pattern for the class-based view is coded as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'update-profile/$', user_isnt_blocked(views.UpdateProfile.as_view()), name="update-profile"),]
```

The class-based view is as follows:

```
class UpdateProfile(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UpdateProfile, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        return super(UpdateProfile, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request):
        ...
```

Any help with what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any error while calling view?

Comment: There was no error when calling the view.  The decorator itself is what's giving me the problem. I've followed the examples used on the web and other posts related to this.

Comment: I suspect `self` parameter in wrapper function. Only three parameter required `request, *args, **kwargs`. & return function should be  `func(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Kaushal, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.  Any other thoughts?  Is there something that might be preventing the logging from happening from within the wrapper?